# JSON not parsed in rails post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

In rails I have an JSON api I'm building. When testing my create action the result isn't parsed properly. Any nested attributes are in json and left unparsed.

### Params content

```
{"user"=>
  "\"id\":511,\"first_name\":\"Bryon\",\"last_name\":\"Hartmann\",\"email\":\"lexi@yahoo.com\",\"password_digest\":\"$2a$04$KeIkq/mRyxH2pLwjYW/EzuJCZMk4rHOLvnffyGjW8NwZhQkUubkWW\",\"admin\":false,\"created_at\":\"2014-11-23T02:38:38.487Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2014-11-23T02:38:38.487Z\"}",
 "controller"=>"api/users",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

### Example

```
# Controller Action
def create
  @user = User.new user_params

  if @user.save
    respond_with @user
  else
    error_message = { notice: @user.errors.full_messages }
    respond_with error_message, status: 401
  end
end

# Test
it 'responds with 200 on success' do
  user = build :user
  post :create, user: user.to_json

  expect(response).to be_success
  expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice while building REST api's is to send the params as plain http attributes. For a post request they can be encoded within the message body (application/x-www-form-urlencoded).

This is best explained by the following curl command:

```
curl --data "user[last_name]=testak&user[first_name]=chuck" http://example.com/users
```

What you've done, however is this:

```
curl --data "user=\{\"last_name\":\"Hartmann\, \"first_name\":\"Bryon\"}" http://example.com/users
```

The correct request for json payload woul be:

```
curl --header "CONTENT_TYPE: application/json" --data "\{\"user\":\{\"last_name\":\"Hartmann\, \"first_name\":\"Bryon\"\}\}\" http://example.com/users
```

Personally i prefer the first option, however this is up to the api designer.

In order to convert json payload into a params hash in rails, you can set the Content-Type" header of your request to "application/json"

In order to use the first option within a rspec controller test you do:

```
 post :create, user: user.attributes
```

For the second option, perform:

```
 post :create, user.to_json, "CONTENT_TYPE" => 'application/json'
```

Comment: Turns out it's possible to automatically convert json payload http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters; I've updated the answer